# sitefinity ActionResult missing query string

Tags: sitefinity

I have widget and in the ActionResult method it get the query string as parameters. The widget takes the   query string and calls a API. Is there anyway I can display a message to the view if its missing the query string?

Code

```
public ActionResult Index(string UserId, string BlogId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, do whatever you want

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId)){
  // you get the idea
}
```

I would do one of the following

- Add a property to the model, then handle that state in the view
- Load a custom view that's just the message (cleanest)
- Check for the empty querystring and do a return this.RedirectPermanent(url); to add the querystring to the page so there's no way it loads without something.

Comment: Could use ViewBag too... but I like the typed state of it being in the model https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc